# Searching a value inside a multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm currently using this:

```
foreach($hash_list as $key => $val){
    if(in_array($search_this,$hash_list[$key])){
        echo 'Found value in key '.$key;
        break;
    }
}
```

To find `$search_this` in this:

```
$hash_list = array();
$hash_list["a"] = array("dfv8p","hi8o7","d2l9f","qhx13","c7duz");
$hash_list["b"] = array("pdsyt","jjivh","nj12b","19tm2","ltsqp");
$hash_list["c"] = array("67s6q","tlwu7","c9p77","7airj","j7tej");
```

Is there a better way to find the key for this situation? `$hash_list` has about 500 arrays with 5 elements each inside.

Comment: @Sergey No php built-in function that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Deadpool: @Sergey No php built-in function that I'm missing?

I dont think so. But I think it's may be little faster, but I'm not sure

```
$hash_list = array();
$hash_list["a"] = "dfv8p, hi8o7, d2l9f, qhx13, c7duz";
$hash_list["b"] = "pdsyt, jjivh, nj12b, 19tm2, ltsqp";
$hash_list["c"] = "67s6q, tlwu7, c9p77, 7airj, j7tej";

foreach($hash_list as $key => $val){
    if(strpos($hash_list[$key], $search_this) !== false) {
        echo 'Found value in key '.$key;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `list()` too ;)

```
<?php
$hash_list = array();
$hash_list["a"] = array("dfv8p","hi8o7","d2l9f","qhx13","c7duz");
$hash_list["b"] = array("pdsyt","jjivh","nj12b","19tm2","ltsqp");
$hash_list["c"] = array("67s6q","tlwu7","c9p77","7airj","j7tej");

$searchParam = "67s6q";
while(list($a,$b) = each($hash_list))
{
if(in_array($searchParam,$b))
{
echo "$searchParam found in $a\n";
}
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
67s6q found in c
```

Comment: but is it better? cause I'm not sure haha

Answer (score 0):

You can use user build functions like this

```
function isValueExist($hash_list,$needle){
 foreach($hash_list as $val){
  if(in_array($needle,array_values($val))) return 1;
 }
}
```

Usage :-

```
if (isValueExist($hash_list,"d2l9f")){
    //DO you things here
  }
```